# Tag *prototypejs*

Tags: suporte, tags

#### Situação

Eu estava estudando `JS` e vi a tag [prototypejs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototypejs), mas só tem um pergunta vinculada, na maioria se usa [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo).

#### Opinião

Eu preferiria que fosse [prototype](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype), pois é a propriedade do JS, não se usa [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo) em JS, mas como aqui é o SOpt, compreendo a tradução.

#### Duvida

- A tag [prototypejs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototypejs) é um equivoco, foi criada sem querer?
- Se não foi criada sem querer, qual é a correta? (só porque [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo) não tem muitas perguntas, não quer disser que esta correto, pode ter sido por influencia).

Comment: PrototypeJS não é um [framework](http://prototypejs.org)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A tag prototypejs é um equivoco, foi criada sem querer?

Não, ela se refere a um framework para JavaScript chamado [PrototypeJS](http://prototypejs.org/).

> Se não foi criada sem querer, qual é a correta? (só porque protótipo não tem muitas perguntas, não quer disser que esta correto, pode ter sido por influencia).

Já a tag [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo), essa não se refere ao conceito de protótipo que existe no JavaScript, e sim ao que está escrito em sua wiki:

> Protótipo é um produto de trabalho da fase de testes e/ou planejamento de um projeto. Pode se referir a um automóvel (como um carro conceptual), avião, nave espacial, navio ou qualquer outra embarcação, veículo de transporte ou produto da engenharia, como, por exemplo, um porto ou uma usina hidrelétrica, uma turbina, uma bomba hidráulica, etc.
>
> Na Engenharia de Software, protótipo é um sistema/modelo (um website ou outro software) sem funcionalidades inteligentes (acesso à banco de dados, por exemplo), podendo conter apenas funcionalidades gráficas. Utilizado para fins de ilustração e melhor entendimento, geralmente em reuniões entre a equipe de Análise de Sistemas e o contratante.

Ou seja, não existe uma tag para se referir ao conceito de protótipo no JavaScript, o jeito é se contentar apenas com a tag [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) mesmo.

Comment: Então esta tag estaria sendo usada incorretamente? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42962/o-que-%C3%A9-prot%C3%B3tipo-javascript

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert sim, e não apenas nessa pergunta, existem várias outras no site utilizando essa tag de maneira errada.

Comment: Creio que seria apropriado então criar a tag `prototype`, pois estar perguntas se referem apenas a esta propriedade do JS, e assim as alterar.

Comment: @Guilherme, é só adotar uma tag e ajudar o SOpt a catalogar melhor o conteúdo ;)

Comment: Reparei que **todas** as perguntas na tag `protótipo` se referem ao *prototype*  do JavaScript, nenhuma é sobre prototipação (de modo que a descrição da tag é que está inconsistente com seu uso). Se removermos essa tag de todas as perguntas, a própria tag será removida do sistema após alguns dias, junto com sua descrição (o que pode levar alguém a recriá-la no futuro inadvertidamente). Tenho uma sugestão a respeito, mas vou colocar numa pergunta separada já que a questão do PrototypeJS já está esclarecida.